# How to measure Oscilloscope's self random jitter

Tags: noise, measurement

I want to measure how much noise is a certain oscilloscope responsible for. Up until now we (my team) have used the approach of inserting a square wave and measuring the random jitter RMS. This method assumes there is no noise from the signal generator (minimal noise), which is not good enough for us.

- Other than that is this a correct approach? If not what is wrong with it?
- Is there a way to evaluate the random noise generated from within the scope itself without using an external signal?

P.s. 
To answer the questions in comments below, we are trying to evaluate an oscilloscope but we have a small noise budget aloud in the system while measuring (I cannot disclose other details). We are currently considering [DPO70000SX series](https://uk.tek.com/oscilloscope/dpo70000sx) with 33GHz and 200Gs/s. Our goal at the moment is to measure the RMS [random jitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter#Random_jitter) in the time domain which is the standard deviation on the [total jitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter#Total_jitter) distribution.

Any other suggestion on how to evaluate this oscilloscope are most welcome.

Comment: How do you factor in noise from the signal generator supplying the square wave?

Comment: We assumed the noise from the signal generator is 0 which is wrong. This is the exact reason we are not satisfied with the method. I will edit the question to include this information.

Comment: You'd need to observe something that has less phase noise than your oscilloscope's reference. Usually, oscilloscope references are specified to a certain frequency stability, at least, and often even for phase noise. Do you have such numbers? would allow us to narrow down options.

Comment: Also, what else in measurement/lab equipment do you have in reach? I mean, we can certainly recommend you use a well-conditioned caesium clock, but …

Comment: I have mostly standard clock generators (3GHz holzeorth\AWG). I do not think I have access to a caesium clock. I am looking for a method to do this without any outside equipment.

Comment: Rubidium clocks are cheaper

Comment: If you have a second oscilloscope of exactly the same kind, you could perform the measurement on both at the same time, so that you can subtract them...

Comment: Havatok, can you clarify what you're after?  Are you looking for noise in the amplitude (you mention RMS) or within the time base (some have mentioned atomic clocks)? Is it in X or Y axes?

Comment: Forget rubidium and caesium clocks -- they have good long term stability but short-term jitter (like phase noise above 1Hz) is dependent on the onboard PLL. This means a fixed frequency temperature-stabilized oscillator will provide lower jitter at a much cheaper price. Now, what is the scope bandwidth? At what frequency do you want to measure? And also, are you interested in cycle to cycle jitter? Or period jitter? Or phase noise? Or... other?

Comment: "I want to measure how much noise is a certain oscilloscope responsible for" - why?

Comment: @peufeu That (good PLLs) is what I meant with well-conditioned :) Anyway, it's kind of sad that, despite this being an immensely interesting question with a lot of extremely interesting aspects, havakok hasn't said anything :( I can see how this is a rabbit hole of questions OP is getting into, but I'd really love to see someone react with domain-specific knowledge! But that would require havakok to state  what the purpose of all the question is :(

Comment: @PaulUszak I want to measure jitters. Jitters are the statistic distribution of inaccuracies in the time domain as far as was explained to me. and If I am not mistaken the RMS is the STD for this statistic.Kindly, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @BruceAbbott it is a great question. We need to evaluate a new oscilloscope for our lab we cannot have it inserting noise to our system and destroying our measurements.

Comment: @peufeu I am interested in Rj RMS. we are talking about a 33GHz Tektronix 200Gs/s.

Comment: Tektronix scopes usually have maximum clock and trigger jitter specified in the datasheet. Are you trying to verify that your scope meets its specs, or do you want to measure the actual jitter in particular operating conditions? What is the maximum amount of jitter you can accept?

Comment: That's way above my league LOL. Considering the $250k "starting price" of such equipment, discussing with one of the manufacturer's engineers about your specific requirements should be an expected part of the sales process, if only to be able to select between the myriad of options... Consider talking to a Tek field applications engineer (I think this is the correct English translation?) about your setup, it's their job to make sure you can do your job ;)

Comment: You could rent the scope (and the engineer) for a demo and evaluation. Even if this costs you a few k$ on such a price tag its a no brainer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a square wave signal will not get your desired results unless you can control the square wave very precisely, which is not easy. An easy way to measure noise in such a system is to use a sine source, with as little noise as possible (but not overly so), use a power splitter and connect it to two inputs of the scope. Then sample the inputs and store the **raw** samples. Using cross correlation, you can eliminate the noise of the signal source you have used and get the noise of each channel. But be aware that there are certain noise sources within the scope that are equal on all channels and thus will cancel out when you do cross correlation. An important one of these noise sources is the noise of the sampling clock, which is correlated between channels.

If you want to measure the sampling clock jitter, you have to start with a known good signal, which has a noise that is lower than the jitter you expect from the scope. As I guess you want to measure in the GHz range, this will be most likely be a special DRO or if you cannot find a DRO with low enough noise a CSO. Unfortunately, a CSO is prohibitively expensive to buy, unless you are at a university that owns one. Alternatively you can ask your national metrology institute whether you can stop buy for some measurements.